# [Javascript]Get coordinate from openlayers map

Tags: javascript, openlayers, coordinate

I would get the coordinate from an openlayers map.
When I open my page I would that when I click on a button, I have received the coordinate of top bottom left and the upper right.

```
 <html>
<head>
  <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
      <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
        map.addLayer(wms);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
      </script>
<input type="button" text="Get Coordinate from map">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [getExtent()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getExtent) function of the Map object.

> Returns
>
> {OpenLayers.Bounds} A Bounds object
>   which represents the lon/lat bounds of
>   the current viewPort.

It will return you an [OpenLayers.Bounds](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html#OpenLayers.Bounds) object, which will have the top, left, bottom and right coordinates of the current view.

Comment: You can use .toBBOX() to get a string version of the bounds, and you can generate your button to this using any standard Javascript approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [map.getCenter()](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getCenter) ?
(this is in case you want the center coordinates of the map in lat lon, but it's not really clear what coordinate you want)